# IE fails, when calling functions from external javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a piece of code that can be simplified to this:

```
var s='' ; 

s += "<"+"script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://somehost.com/scripts/FooFunctions.js\">\n";
s += "<"+"/script>" ;
s += "<"+"script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
s += "FooFunction(42, 'i love cats');\n";
s += "<"+"/script>" ;

document.write(s) ;
```

In all browsers except IE, this executes as you'd expect - functions from somehost.com/scripts/FooFunctions.js work as expected.

In Internet Explorer, this fails.

Googling this seems difficult. I've found the occasional post witht the same problem, but no solution.

(There is a valid reason that the external file needs to be included ***from javascript*** this way, and that the pgae can not have a `<script src="http://somehost.com/scripts/FooFunctions.js">` inserted in it.)

To be clear, the question is: How can I make the above piece of code function the same in Internet Explorer as it does in e.g. FireFox?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works in IE

```
function addJsFile(jsFileLocation){
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript'; 
    script.src=jsFileLocation; 
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
addJsFile("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js");
setTimeout(function(){alert(jQuery);},1000);
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, but this probably works because script inclusion by DOM injection (what you are doing here), doesn't parallelize script downloads - they are loaded serially. Hence, it's guaranteed that it's available when you reach the alert();

Comment: I actually already tried this method, and it didn't appear to solve the problem, but I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like IE is calling `FooFunction` before the script is loaded. You can test this by using `setTimeout("FooFunction(42, 'i love cats')", 1000);` assuming one second is enough time for the script to load, this call will succeed.

If you can't use a framework like jQuery to load the scripts, which will provide you with a callback when the script loads, you might be able to hack your own with `setInterval`, checking for `FooFunction`

Comment: In IE you can add an onreadystatechange handler (similar to AJAX) to the script tag to know when it has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the document.write call is complete it will run the function in the second script tag. Regardless of whether or not the external script has loaded yet. This should not just be an IE problem but should effect all browsers. Are you sure that it is not effecting other browsers as they have the external script cached? What happens when you clear your cache and try again in another browser?

Anyways, in an ideal world you should just be able to use .onload on the script tag but I'm 99% sure that there is problems with onload not firing on script tags in IE6 so we need to resort to using onload on the window element instead. This will event will not fire until all scripts have been downloaded including external js files like above.